# "Than" and "as" as subject - singular or plural?

Tags: verb-agreement, pronominal-agreement

### **"Than" and "as" as subjects, objects and complements**.

Under this topic title(581), in Michael Swan's Practical English Usage (3rd edition, page 575), he says that *"**than** and **as** can replace subject in clauses (rather like relative pronouns)"*, and there the following sentences are given as examples:

> 1. He worries more **than** is necessary. (NOT...more than **it/what** is necessary.)
> 2. There were a lot of people at the exhibition - more **than** came last year. (NOT...more than **they** came last year.)
> 3. The train might be late **as** happened yesterday. (NOT...as **it** happened yesterday.)
> 4. We have got food for as many people **as** want it. (NOT...as **they** want it.)

Also, PEU explains:

> Common expressions with **as** in place of a subject: *as follows; as
>   was expected; as was agreed; as is well known.*
>
> 5. I have prepared a new plan, **as** follows. (NOT...as **it** follows.)
> 6. I am sending you the bill, **as** was agreed. (NOT...as **it** was agreed.)

When I examine the sentence 4, I understand that the verb **want** is used in the plural form in accordance with the noun **people**, and therefore, I assume that the pronoun **as** here is also a plural subject. In the same way, in the sentence 6 **was** is used in the singular form in accordance with the singular noun **bill**.

It seems to me the PEU contradicts with the definition of **as follows** by the [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/as-follows): *"This term is always put in the singular (“follows”) even though it applies to numerous items and is frequently followed by a colon."*

Now my questions are: *Can I assume in the sentence 5,  **follows** is used in the singular form in accordance with the number of the singular noun **plan**, and **as**, as a subject, is singular?*

If I rewrite the sentence as: *I have prepared some new **plans**, as **follow**,*
is it acceptable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are not replacements for subjects, but prepositions introducing comparative clauses. Such clauses are typically reduced, usually obligatorily but sometimes optionally. In 2. for example, "than came last year" has the obligatorily reduced comparative clause "came last year" as complement of the preposition "than". In full in would be the ungrammatical  *"... more (children) than children came last year". Btw, "more" is a fused determiner-head, interpreted as "more children".

Comment: @BillJ, yes my instinct is also that they are reduced clauses. But, why does Swan warn against their full form as shown in brackets 'NOT...'? Reduced clauses cannot be expanded?

Comment: I don't agree with his bracketed full forms. I'd say that the full form in 2. would be the ungrammatical *"more (people) than people came last year".

Comment: "If I rewrite the sentence as: *I have prepared some new plans, as follow,* is it acceptable?" -- technically, absolutely. Why not? However, *as follows* is a set phrase so it may not need any change; any other word in the same template **can** and thus **may** assume a singular form.

Comment: You already know this from the  dictionary . com cited.

Comment: @Kris Is Michael Swan wrong when he says *as* in the set phrase *as follows* is functioning as a subject? If he is right, what about that subject's becoming sometimes plural? Think of Swan's other common expressions list. For example, in 6, *was* is used to go with *bill*. If I write it as *we are sending you the bills, as were agreed*; is it okay?

Comment: "As" cannot possibly be a subject. "As follows" is an idiomatic preposition with the prep "as" heading the PP "as follows", meaning roughly "as what comes next". Btw, I would strongly advise you to get a better grammar book!